# Is it a way to easily copy records from one CloudKit container to an other?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have an other project and some of the records I need there too. Is it an easy way to copy them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one app you can access multiple containers. instead of using:

```
    container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
```

you can use:

```
    container = CKContainer(identifier: "another_container")
```

as the identifier use whatever you have specified at your application Capabilities (Specify custom containers)

You can then read records from 1 container and write them to the other.